# R mapview: Point border color by group

Tags: r, colors, maps, r-mapview

I am having trouble controlling the color of the border of a point.

I've got a data frame of addresses that I would like to color according to a categorical variable, `Group`. These are single points, not polygons. I would like to plot *just* the outlines of the points, not the inner regions itself. I thought that I could handle this using the `color` argument and setting `alpha.regions = 0, alpha = 1`. Replication code listed below

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mapview)
library(Rcolorbrewer)
mapview(breweries %>% filter(!is.na(number.seasonal.beers)), 
    color = c("firebrick1", "darkolivegreen", "magenta4", "darkgoldenrod4", "red", "blue"),                
    col.regions = c("firebrick1", "darkolivegreen", "magenta4", "darkgoldenrod4", "red", "blue"),        
    alpha = 1,
    alpha.regions = 0,
    zcol = "number.seasonal.beers",
    legend = T,
    layer.name = "Breweries")
```

While this successfully displays the outlines of the circle, omitting the filling of the region, there is no apparent relationship between the color of the circle outline and `Group`. Is there a "`color.outline`" type argument that can connect the `Group` indicator and the `Group`? Is there a better means by which to assign color to the to plotted addresses? Any guidance would be much appreciated